# ScrollView does't work on ItemTemplte in collectionView on android

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I have define  ItemTemplate in CollectionView - with many Label in the itemTemplate.
I expect to be able to scroll and see all the label and this what happaned
on windows when i run it

but on android its not happaned - i can't see the scroll and i don't
find the reson for this

Code:

```
 <CollectionView                  
 ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

     <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyModels">

         <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 24" HeightRequest="300" StrokeThickness="1" BackgroundColor="White" >

             <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5"  RowDefinitions="6*,2*,Auto" >

                <ScrollView>
                     
                     <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5" Spacing="5" >
                     
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        <Lable Text="text1" />
                        
                     </VerticalStackLayout>
                 
                </ScrollView>
             </Grid>

         </Border>

     </DataTemplate>

 </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview)

> Warning
>
> ScrollView objects should not be nested. In addition, ScrollView
> objects should not be nested with other controls that provide
> scrolling, such as CollectionView, ListView, and WebView.

Comment: so any recommendation to how solve this ?

Comment: design your UI so it doesn't require nested scrolling

Comment: yes, but how to do it without nested scrolling ?

Comment: I don't know anything about your app, your UI or your data

Comment: Simple, my border is limited on HeightRequest="300" - and i have about 16 labels to show. its not fit for the height of this - and i need some way to scroll it. i don't know how to do it ( this is my first maui app that i writing )